# Is WIdi compatible with Apple TV?

Tags: appletv

Is it possible to stream WIDI to Apple TV? I have laptop with WIDI adapter and i want to stream from laptop to Apple tv

Answer (score 1):

Nope Apple TV does not support WiDi.

You should look for AirPlay apps (Some are available on Windows)!